What alternatives to conduit are there for a hay barn?
I have been trying to understand the NEC around Ag buildings (547). As far as I understand I need to use UF, MC, or conduit. There is hay in the barn, so using UF appears to be against code. I originally wanted to run PVC conduit indoors and switch to light-tight flexible conduit for 4 plugs outdoors under a roof.
My main issue is getting conduit around the poles in the barn without having to hand bend conduit. The bends would be pretty tight or within limited space (1.5 inches between pole and metal wall). Is there an alternative?
I was thinking that I should just use light-tight flexible conduit everywhere, but that seems overkill and expensive.

I think you mean liquid-tight flexible conduit...though which one you mean I'm not sure (there's liquid-tight nometallic and liquid-tight metallic conduit.)

Your main issue is that  due to hay dust 547.1A 1.1 puts you on an "dust-explosion-proof" wiring regime per Article 502 which it refers the wiring methods to. https://thenecwiki.com/2021/02/article-547/ unfortunately that reference is vague - there isn't a "part II" there's "classII, division I" and "class II division 2" and it's unclear what the intent of 547 is since it refers to "part II" not one of those actual designations found in 502. https://thenecwiki.com/2021/02/article-502/

There is a part II there, it's the wiring methods section @Ecnerwal -- however, the problem is that the stuff in 547.1 and 547.20 isn't clear about under what circumstances Article 502 wiring methods are required.  (i.e. not all ag dusts are combustible, but the text in Art. 547 does not make a distinction)

@Ecnerwal I was thinking this: https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/conduit-conduit-fittings-raceways/conduit/southwire-reg-10-liquidtight-flexible-metallic-conduit/55082723/p-1444442893486-c-6423.htm?missingVariation=true

My main question is how to get around tight corners specifically the pole without doing hand bending. But I understand that there is another question re dust proof ness

Hand bending isn't the end of the world. You handle tight corners with two bends--one to turn parallel to the obstruction and one to enter the gap. Getting to know the math is the mildly tricky part. You may be able to avoid the bending with pre-bent elbows.

I guess the question is then if it is easier to bend EMT or PVC. PVC seems like a bigger pain than EMT.

@madtowneast There exist electric heaters for bending PVC conduit - some heat externally (essentially an oven) and others heat from within the PVC (a hot wire). Within a few minutes a 2-3 foot section of stiff PVC conduit turns into a floppy, limp noodle that can be easily formed into shapes one can't possibly pull wire through! A bit of experience helps one make complex bends that are pullable. Electric heat gun or propane torch also work well for softening and bending PVC.
